# Typing effect Python

Tags: python

I was working on a typing-like effect for printing strings in Python. My code is below:

```
import time, sys
def type(str):
    for letter in(str):
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        time.sleep(0.03)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    print()
```

And this code works fine, but instead of using `os.system('clear')`, I would like the letters to  "disappear backwards", sort of like how it prints letter by letter, except I want the string to the disappear letter by letter. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm certain that there's a library that does this, but I have no idea which one.